# How do I make a childless node have an input box that will post a number so it can call a python function?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, svg

As the question states, I need a childless node to act as input (pretty input preferably) so I can call a Python function and return a value. I would like it all to happen in javascript so it's seemless. Does anyone know how I can do that? It may involve doing something to the following-

```
h = t.append("g").classed("body-group", !0);
                            return h.append("image").classed("body-box", !0).attr("xlink:href", "{% static 'body box bg.png' %}").attr("width", 1e-6).attr("height", 1e-6)
```

[Here is the JSFiddle. Hopefully it helps you understand what I mean by childless node.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzck10pt/)